# Value of the Application.StartupPath of a program

Tags: c#, process

I have program1 that will boot from program2 like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\myfolder\myprogram.exe");
```

In the program2 i have a variable with value: Application.StartupPath.
If i launch the program2 with Process.Start(@"C:\myfolder\myprogram.exe") from the program1 on the desktop the Application.StartupPath of myprogram is desktop and not myfolder. Why? Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sis because you started the program from desktop. It's a bit like the "start in" box from a windows shortcut. I usually use the code below as it'll never be wrong as it looks at where the current executable is located, but you could also start it with processstartinfo and working directory

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string ThisFolder = new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Directory.FullName;
```

Regards

Liam

Comment: Just a little bug: GetExecutingAssembly() and not GetExecutingAssembly. Many thanks!

Comment: Ahh sorry, I write VB.NET and then used a converter to add the code for you in C# lol Feel free to click accepted answer if it worked for you (I've edited my answer to show the change you mentioned)